# Content Placement In a Div

Tags: html

How to I get .a to be on the far left, .b to be in the center, and .c to be on the far right?

```html
  <div class="footer1">
              <span class="a">Located At</span>
              <span class="b">Phone Number</span>
              <span class="c">Website By</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a flexbox.

```css
.footer1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer1 span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="footer1">
  <span class="a">Located At</span>
  <span class="b">Phone Number</span>
  <span class="c">Website By</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but how to I get "located at" touching the far left and "website by" touching the far right?

Comment: You can use ".b { margin: auto}" instead of ".footer1 span { margin: auto}"

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the span to be on the far edge i would recommend this CSS Code:

```
.footer1{
   display: block;
   text-align:center; 
}

.a {   
   float: left; 
}

.b {
   margin: 0, auto;
   text-align: center; 
}

.c {
   float: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```css
.footer1{
    display: flex;  
}
.footer1 span{
    width: 33%;
}
.c{
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer1">
  <span class="a">Located At</span>
  <span class="b">Phone Number</span>
  <span class="c">Website By</span>
</div>
```

include .b{ text-align: center} in the style if you want to centralize the middle element